# How to use Dart HTML's DirectoryEntry and DirectoryReader classes?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I need an example for using the DirectoryEntry and DirectoryReader classes in Dart:HTML. The following code read an image file from img directory and load it as an image element in the browser.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: 'img/car.jpg');
  querySelector('body').append(image);
}
```

Here is the structure of my webapp directory:

[image: webapp directory's structure]

I need to dynamically list and use the content of img directory.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Dart:HTML'? In the browser?

Comment: The classes are part of dart:html library in api.dartlang.org: [DirectoryEntry](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/DirectoryEntry.html) and [DirectoryReader](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/DirectoryReader.html)

Comment: I want to use these two classes to list the content of an image directory in my webapp.

Comment: So you want to run this on the server? Then you should use `dart:io` not `dart:html`

Comment: No. The client-side webapp has an image directory whose content can be accessed by specifying their filename. Instead of hard-coding the filenames in my app, I want to dynamically list and use the content of that directory.

Comment: I have added an example code and image of the directory to my question for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'img/car.jpg' is a file on the server which the browser requests from your server when you assign the path to an `<img>` element.
`DirectoryEntry` and `DirectoryReader` work on the client only.

What you need is that the server provides an API (e.g. JSON) that lets you request a list of files/directories from your server (e.g. of your `img` directory).
If your server has directory listing enabled you could alternatively send a simple HTTP request with `/img` as URL and parse the response.

Comment: I suspected this but was not sure. Thank you for the clarification. I'll use an HTTP request.

Comment: The APIs for `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectoryReader` are part of the FileSystem API for accessing and manipulating a client-side file system. Consider it almost like Cookies or indexeddb with more features. See this for more information: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/